A set of values ​from a discrete uniform distribution is scaled down by the same factor
Use MATLAB's randi function to generate a set of values ​​that conform to discrete uniform distribution, such as {0,1,2,3,4,5}. If this set of values ​​is divided by an integer 10 at the same time, then {0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5} still conforms to discrete uniform distribution?

(This is related to your prior question.)
A uniform discrete distribution means that each member of the sample space has equal (nonzero) probability. When you divide your output by ten, you wind up with:
$$
P(X = 0) = \dfrac{1}{6}\\
P(X = 0.1) = \dfrac{1}{6}\\
P(X = 0.2) = \dfrac{1}{6}\\
P(X = 0.3) = \dfrac{1}{6}\\
P(X = 0.4) = \dfrac{1}{6}\\
P(X = 0.5) = \dfrac{1}{6}\\
$$
Consequently, yes, dividing by ten preserves the "discrete uniform" characteristic of the distribution, just uniform over the sample space $S = \left\{0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5\right\}$ instead of $S^{\prime} = \left\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\right\}$.
In fact, any injective function $f$ from the initial sample space $S$ to the ending sample space $S^{\prime}$ is going to preserve the "discrete uniform" characteristic.
$$
P(X = x_1) = p \\
P(X = x_2) = p \\
\vdots \\
P(X = x_n) = p
$$
Since $f$ is injective (sends distinct elements to distinct elements), then for $Y = f(X)$:
$$
P(Y = f(x_1)) = p \\
P(Y = f(x_2)) = p \\
\vdots \\
P(Y = f(x_n)) = p
$$
$Y$ is still discrete uniform.
